# Perspective crashes on startup with "Couldn't create texture from file"

Tags: technical-issues, perspective

When I try to run Perspective on my Windows 11 Laptop it gives the following error on startup:

> ..\Source\Graphics\GraphicsContext.cpp(1819): Couldn't create texture from file
>
> Cancel | Try Again | Continue

Clicking either Try Again or Continue results in a crash:

> Woops! That shouldn't have happened...
> A small crash report will be created.

This issue occurs regardless of whether I install [through Steam](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1109410/Perspective/) or [the Digipen website](https://games.digipen.edu/games/perspective).

The game runs as expected when I try playing on my Steam Deck or desktop with a GeForce GTX 1070, which makes me believe the problem may be related to my laptop's integrated Intel graphics.

#### System Specifications

- OS: Windows 11 Pro (Build 22621)
- Processor: Intel Core i5-8365U CPU @ 1.60GHz
- Graphics: Intel UHD Graphics 620
- RAM: 16 GB
- Laptop Model: Lenovo ThinkPad T490s

#### Screenshot

[image: Startup error]